# Django i whant a default valure for a ForeignKey defined on self

Tags: django, foreign-keys, default, self

i got this model :

```
class bob(models.Model):
  pre = models.ForeignKey('self',blank=False,default= ? )
```

I have two needs!

- As you see i when to be sure that every bob as a pre but i need to create by hand the root bob that as itself for a pre. (is there a way to create the root with blank=True then migrate back to blank=Flase )
- the default must be this root bob

Comment: Your code snippet isn't correct. At minimum, the `class` keyword should be entirely lowercase. Please copy and paste the code into your question instead of re-typing it, which can introduce typos and lead us down the wrong path.

Comment: Noted @Chris   but code not in english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set null true, create your first bob and then migrate to null false.

You can use this for the default :

default=lambda: Bob.objects.first()

Comment: Thanks for this it's what i have done but i wanted a solution that dosn't involve a deployement operation.